# Columns of an index contain all PKs. Not efficient?

Tags: database, indexing

For example,
`TABLE_A` has `a`, `b`, `c` columns.
`a` is a PK and indexed as `PK_TABLE_A`. And there is an index called `IDX_TABLE_A` that contains `b`, `a` in order.

```
SELECT a, b
FROM TABLE_A
WHERE a = @P1 AND b = @P2
```

This query will use `PK_TABLE_A` and `b` predicate will be ignored.

```
SELECT a, b
FROM TABLE_A
WHERE b = @P2
```

This query will use `IDX_TABLE_A`. But `a` doesn't have to be indexed. Being an `included column` will be more efficient.

Are there any reasonable cases `IDX_TABLE_A` indexes `a` column?

Comment: I don't understand the question: you already have all PK columns in an index - the index that enforces the PK

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name You mean `PK_TABLE_A`? I know. But I saw an index like `IDX_TABLE_A` in a production DB. Which seems poorly created to me. But I wanted to be sure before I change it.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Ah, "Columns of an index contain all PKs" means that an index contains all PK columns _and more_. So not just PKs, but also other columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Including columns in an index that do not help with locating particular rows can still improve performance of a query, by allowing values for those columns to be retrieved directly from the index record, without following a reference from the index record to the table record to obtain them. Queries whose selected columns are all included in one (or more) indexes are called "covered" queries; an index "covers" all the desired columns and the database does not need to access the table rows themselves to build the query results.

The index on (b,a) in TABLE_A might exist to speed up a query that matches on b, or possibly both b and a (these could be exact matches, range matches or other kinds), and wants to quickly return only the values of b and a in the query results, but not the values of column c.

Comment: Correct me If I'm wrong: `IDX_TABLE_A` still doesn't have to index `a`. If a query uses `a` and `b`, `PK_TABLE_A` will be used because it has the best selectivity. When reading `a` value, `a` can be an `included column` instead of an index key column.

Comment: Some database engines make a distinction between columns in an index that are part of the ordering and those that are merely included, but some do not. You did not say which database engine you are using; if it is one that makes the distinction, then you are correct, the a column only needs to be an included column, not a proper part of the index itself. (In fact, for some database engines and index types, the primary keys themselves are stored in the index records regardless of whether they are declared part of an index or included in it; some use a row ID instead.)

Comment: Didn't know this is dependent on DBMS. Thank you